# Add attributes to IXmlNode

Tags: c#, xml, windows-store-apps

In windows app store they changed the `XmlNode` to `IXmlNode` !!! , I tried to add attribute to the node by the normal way but I failed they removed `Attributes.Append(---)`.

Is there any solution to append attributes to the node ?

```
 XmlDocument tileData = TileUpdateManager.GetTemplateContent(TileTemplateType.TileSquarePeekImageAndText01);
            IXmlNode bindingnode = tileData.SelectSingleNode("binding");
            XmlAttribute newAttribute = tileData.CreateAttribute("branding");
            newAttribute.Value = "name";
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried and I found the solution is

```
bindingnode.Attributes.SetNamedItem(newAttribute);
```